# How can I introduce a constant reference line based on an aggregation to a Kusto timechart?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

I've got a simple KQL query that plots the (log of the) count of all exceptions over 90 days:

```
exceptions
| where timestamp > ago(90d)
| summarize log(count()) by bin(timestamp, 1d)
| render timechart
```

What I'd like to do is add some reference lines to the timechart this generates. Based on [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/charts#reference-line), this is pretty straightforward:

```
| extend ReferenceLine = 8
```

The complicating factor is that I'd like these reference lines to be based on aggregations of the value I'm plotting. For instance, I'd like a reference line for the minimum, mean, and 3rd quartile values.

Focusing on the first of these (minimum), it turns out that you can't use `min()` outside of `summarize()`. But I can use this within an `extend()`.

I was drawn to `min_of()`, but this expects a list of arguments instead of a column. I'm thinking I could probably expand the column into a series of values, but this feels hacky and would fall down beyond a certain number of values.

What's the idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: I had to explicitly declare a `xcolumn` value for this to work with a [linechart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/visualization-linechart): `| render linechart with(xcolumn = week)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could try something like the following:

```
exceptions
| where timestamp > ago(90d)
| summarize c = log(count()) by bin(timestamp, 1d)
| as hint.materialized=true T
| extend _min = toscalar(T | summarize min(c)),
         _perc_50 = toscalar(T | summarize percentile(c, 50))
| render timechart
```

Comment: Thanks Yoni. This works great. One thing: what is `hint.materialized=true` here? And how is it different to `materialize()`

Comment: it is equivalent to doing something like: `let T = materialize(execptions … | by bin(timestamp, 1d); T | extend _min ...`